# Use loops to count number of records per day in Java

Tags: java, android, loops, arraylist, realm

Bit of a noob question, but what's the best way to build a loop for this situation?
**[Suppose I have this table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwNk1.png)** I want to count how many records are created per day and store each distinct date and their count of records in an arraylist. If a date doesn't have any records in it (e.g. 8/25), the date should still be stored with a count of 0.

The data is being pulled from a Realm table, so SQL queries don't work.

```
ArrayList<Date> days = new ArrayList<Date>();
                ArrayList<Integer> recordsPerDay = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                int count = 0;

                for(countresults = 0; countresults <= results.size(); countresults++){
                    if(tblProposalCorporate.getDateCreated()!=lastWeek)
                    {
                        days.add(tblProposalCorporate.getDateCreated());
                        count = 0;
                    }
                    if (tblProposalCorporate.getDateCreated()==lastWeek)
                    {
                        days.add(tblProposalCorporate.getDateCreated());
                        count+=1;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Sorry! These are all stored in a Realm table.

Comment: Please add this information to your question, and also add the appropriate tags, so others can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly simple actually, just get the minimum and maximum date from Realm:

```
Date minimumDate = realm.where(Proposal.class).mininumDate("dateCreated");
Date maximumDate = realm.where(Proposal.class).maximumDate("dateCreated");
```

Then you can set these dates to zero hour, minute, second, and millisecond:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(minimumDate);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
minimumDate = calendar.getTime();

calendar.setTime(maximumDate);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
maximumDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Now all you need to do is iterate the date and execute queries to get your data count

```
Map<Date, Long> counts = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for(Date iterDate = new Date(minimumDate); iterDate.getTime() <= maximumDate.getTime(); ) {
    calendar.setTime(iterDate);
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    Date nextDay = calendar.getTime();

    counts.put(iterDate, realm.where(Proposal.class).greaterThanOrEqualTo("dateCreated", iterDate).lowerThan("dateCreated", nextDay).count());

    iterDay.setTime(nextDay.getTime());
}
```